# Proof verification and improvement - lower bound for the sum product problem

Tags: solution-verification, products, additive-combinatorics

Thinking about [the sum product conjecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szemer%C3%A9di_theorem), if we consider a set of distinct elements $A=\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$, $\forall a_i\in \mathbb Z^+$, I have derived the following lower bound: $$\max\{|A+A|,|A•A|\}\geq \frac{n^2+5n-2}{4}$$

*Proof*

It can be easily showed that $$2n-1\leq|A+A|\leq \frac{n^2+n}{2}$$
and  $$2n-1\leq|A•A|\leq \frac{n^2+n}{2}$$

This bounds are independent of the correlation between $|A+A|$ and $|A•A|$.

Other hand, $a_i+a_j=a_r+a_s=k$ only if (wlog, $a_i>a_j$,$a_r>a_s$ and $a_i>a_r$) $a_i=a_r+k$ and $a_j=a_s-k$.

Substituting, we get that $$a_ia_j=(a_r+k)(a_s-k)=a_ra_s+k(a_s-a_r)-k^2$$ As $k(a_s-a_r)-k^2<0$ $\forall a_s,a_r,k \in \mathbb Z^+$, we conclude that if $a_i+a_j=a_r+a_s$ then $a_ia_j\neq a_ra_s$. A similar argument can be used conversely to show that if $a_ia_j= a_ra_s$ then $a_i+a_j\neq a_r+a_s$.

Therefore, any decrease in the number of distinct elements of set $A+A$, which ocurr only due to relations $a_i+a_j=a_r+a_s$, implies a non-decrease in the number of distinct elements of set $A•A$; and conversely,  any decrease in the number of distinct elements of set $A•A$, which ocurr only due to relations $a_ia_j=a_ra_s$, implies a non-decrease in the number of distinct elements of set $A+A$. Thus, the maximum total decrease for sets $A+A$ and $A•A$ from the upper independent bound of $\frac{n^2+n}{2}$ stated before is $\frac{n^2+n}{2}-(2n-1)$ jointly for both sets.

Subsequently, we can affirm that $$|A+A|+|A•A|\geq \frac {n^2+n}{2}+2n-1$$ and, subsequently, $$\max\{|A+A|,|A•A|\}\geq \frac{\frac{n^2+n}{2}+2n-1}{2}$$ Operating a bit, we get that  $$\max\{|A+A|,|A•A|\}\geq \frac{n^2+5n-2}{4}$$ As we wanted to prove.

It would be great if you could confirm that the proof is correct, or point out the errors. Also, I would like to know how to derive a tight asymptotic of the form $\Omega (|A|^{1+\epsilon})$ from the bound proved (even if the proof turns out to be wrong), and if the proof could be extended to cover sets with elements in $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb R$.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Checking "by hand", I get that: $$\frac{n^2+5n-2}{4}\geq (n^{2-\frac{1}{2}})$$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z^+$; $$\frac{n^2+5n-2}{4}> (n^{2-\frac{1}{3}})$$ for all $n>48$; $$\frac{n^2+5n-2}{4}> (n^{2-\frac{1}{4}})$$ for all $n>235$; $$\frac{n^2+5n-2}{4}> (n^{2-\frac{1}{5}})$$ for all $n>998$; $$\dots$$ It seems that $$\frac{n^2+5n-2}{4}> (n^{2-\frac{1}{k}})$$ for all $n>4^k-5k-1$.

This suggests that, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $n_0$, such that any set $A$ of at least $n_0$ integers satisfies $\max\{|A+A|,|A•A|\}\geq c|A|^{2-\epsilon}$ (Erdös-Szemeredi conjecture) with an explicit constant $c=1$.

Comment: What does $\Delta \lvert A+A\rvert$ mean?

Comment: @ThomasBloom it is intended to mean "change in the number of distinct elements of A+A"

Comment: Change with respect to what? What is changing here?

Comment: @ThomasBloom, it was a bit confusing; I have edited the OP to make this point clearer, hope is better explained now

Comment: Aside from the problem with your proof, the actual claimed result is also incorrect, since if $A=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ then $\max(\lvert A+A\rvert, \lvert AA\rvert) =o(n^2)$ (see Erdos multiplication table problem).

Comment: @ThomasBloom I do not see the incompatibility of Erdos result and the claimed lower bound... with the same argument you could say that Solymosi's result is also incorrect

Comment: Erdos' result implies, in particular, that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a large enough $n$ such that with $A=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ we have $\max(\lvert A+A\rvert,\lvert AA\rvert) \leq \epsilon n^2$. Your claimed result would imply this is $\geq n^2/4$. This is a contradiction for any $\epsilon<1/4$. Solymosi's result does not contradict the Erdos bound since the exponent of $n$ in his lower bound is $<2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this proof is not valid. I'll rephrase your proof as follows: let $\lvert A\rvert=n$ and call a quadruple $(i,j,r,s)$ (with $1\leq i,j,r,s\leq n$) an additive quadruple if $a_i+a_j=a_r+a_s$, and similarly for multiplicative quadruple.

You give a simple argument that a quadruple cannot be simultaneously both additive and multiplicative - aside from the 'diagonal case' when $\{i,j\}=\{r,s\}$. This is correct.

The count of additive quadruples is a well-studied concept in additive combinatorics, and is usually known as the additive energy, denoted $E_+(A)$, and similarly for multiplicative energy.

Where you go wrong is in deducing about the size of $\lvert A+A\rvert$ or $\lvert AA\rvert$ from this. You seem to be implicitly assuming something like $\lvert A+A\rvert = \frac{n^2+n}{2}-E_+(A)$, in saying something like 'any decrease in the number of distinct elements in $A+A$ which occur only due to [additive quadruples]'. This is obviously wrong anyway, since $E_+(A)$ includes the 'diagonal quadruples' where $\{i,j\}=\{r,s\}$, of which there are $\approx n^2/2$. But even redefining energy to not include these, this is  still wrong.

(Consider, for example, the case when $A=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ - this has very large additive energy, $\asymp n^3$, but $\lvert A+A\rvert \asymp n$.)

Perhaps you don't mean exactly $\lvert A+A\rvert = \frac{n^2+n}{2}-E_+(A)$, but any similar simple formula between the size of the sumset and the additive energy is doomed to fail. The best you can do is a one-way implication, that $\lvert A+A\rvert \geq \lvert A\rvert^4/E_+(A)$, which is a consequence of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Assuming that we use this, the observation that non-diagonal quadruples cannot be simultaneously both additive and multiplicative only obviously gives us the relationship that $\min(E_+(A),E_\times(A))\leq \frac{1}{2}n^4$ (since there are $n^4+O(n^2)$ non-diagonal quadruples in total). (As a test case for your argument, think about the potential worst-case - that half of all $n^4$ possible quadruples are additive and the other half are all multiplicative - what does your argument suggest is the size of the sum and product sets?)

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz consequence above, this means that $\max(\lvert A+A\rvert,\lvert AA\rvert)\geq (2+o(1))n$. This is, of course, trivial, since as you point out we automatically have $\lvert A+A\rvert \geq 2n-1$ anyway.

The sum-product conjecture remains wide-open, and has been studied by many people for decades. While it is possible that there is a simple argument which has been overlooked so far, it is very unlikely. I recommend that you read some of the recent progress on the sum-product conjecture, which contains many beautiful elementary ideas you'd find interesting. (e.g. there is a very elegant argument of Solymosi which yields $\max(\lvert A+A\rvert,\lvert AA\rvert)\gg \lvert A\rvert^{4/3-o(1)}$, a nice account of which is written up here: https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Solymosi.pdf.)

Comment: thanks for your answer! Just one doubt: could you clarify the concepts of "diagonal case" and "diagonal quadruples" with an example? And just a clarification: the beauty of the "proof" is that it is set a bound on the minimum cardinality of the sets $A+A$ and $AA$,based on the relationship of mutual exclusion of addition and multiplication exposed, without dealing with the really difficult task of sizing them. I do not care about the size of each of the sets individually, but jointly they are bounded by their independent lower and upper bounds, and this exclusion relationship.

Comment: By diagonal quadruples I mean e.g. ones of the a+b=a+b or a+b=b+a, which are trivial additive coincidences. 

Your reasoning is invalid, in short, because there is no direct equivalence between 'the size of the sum/product set' and 'the number of additive/multiplicative quadruples', so your observation about the clashes between additive/multiplicative quadruples does not imply anything (non-trivial) about the relationship between the sizes of the sum/product sets.

Comment: as I understand, these diagonal quadruples are all excluded by the independent upper bounds of $\frac{n^2+n}{2}$ for both sets. Every set A+A and AA can be represented with a symmetric square matrix $n\space \times \space n$, in which these diagonal quadruples (if I understood well) are excluded by only taking into account as "unique" values the  ones in the principal diagonal and below, and excluding the rest, which are duplicated. And then is when my reasoning takes place. I am missing something?

Comment: The diagonal vs. non-diagonal issue is easily worked around, as you say, so don't focus on it too much - that is not the problem with your proof, just a side issue. The actual problem with your proof is that there is not a straightforward relation between the sizes of $A+A$ or $AA$ and the number of 'clashes' $a_i+a_j=a_r+a_s$ and $a_ia_j=a_ra_s$, like the one you're implicitly using.

Comment: there is a straightforward relation between the size of $A+A$ **and** $AA$ and the number of 'clashes' of additive and multiplicative quadruples. From the mutual exclusion of both it is derived a minimum size for $|A+A|+|A•A|$ jointly, which in turn implies a lower bound for $\max\{|A+A|,|A•A|\}$. I still do not see how your arguments make the proof process and result invalid.

Comment: As I state in the other comment thread, Erdos' multiplication table result is enough to show that your claimed result is false (and hence certainly the proof must be invalid). The above is my best attempt at trying to explain where you go wrong. It is difficult to explain further unless you write down explicitly what the 'straightforward relation' is you claim in your comment. I claim that any such relation you write down will be false.